# SQL Server : I get an error: "Incorrect syntax near '='. "

Tags: sql-server

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_CaglarDeneme]
    (@stok_kodu varchar(25))
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VAL As Float

    SELECT CASE WHEN sto_mensei IN (REGULE) THEN @VAL = (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod, GETDATE() - 180, GETDATE()) + 
                                                         dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod, GETDATE() - 180, GETDATE()) + 
                                                         dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar(sto_kod, GETDATE() - 180, GETDATE())) - 
                                                        (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar(sto_kod, GETDATE() - 180, GETATE()) +  
                                                         dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ())),
                WHEN sto_mensei in ('PASIF','PROJE') THEN @VAL = (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-90 ,getdate () )+
                                                                  dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate () ) + 
                                                                  dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ())) - 
                                                                 (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ()) +  
                                                                  dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ())),
                WHEN sto_mensei in ( 'YAZLIK','KISLIK') THEN @VAL= (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) +
                                                                    dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) + 
                                                                    dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())) - 
                                                                   (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) +  
                                                                    dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())),
                ELSE '0'
    FROM   dbo.STOKLAR  
    WHERE  (sto_kod=@stok_kodu)

    IF @VAL <0 SET @VAL =0

    RETURN @VAL
END
```

I wonder what is the error I got in this query

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure F_CaglarDeneme, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** it returns a scalar value, not a statement, or boolean result, or anything else. `THEN @VAL=(dbo.fn_F_Ul...` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can't perform assignments after the `THEN`. It only accepts a *column name* or *some other expression of which the value is returned*. Your best bet it to try putting the assignment part before the `CASE WHEN`, or even before the SELECT.

Comment: This is the mistake I get when I run it
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure F_CaglarDeneme, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: For future reference, please edit your code so we can easily read it. This left justified code is very hard to read. Also, explain what you are trying to do. Now we can only tell you what the error is, not how to fix it.

Comment: Peter then what is the solution for the error i get

Comment: *"Peter then what is the solution for the error i get "* Don't try to assign a variable inside the `THEN` is a `CASE` expression; as the comments above have told you.

Comment: You also have a missing `END` for your `CASE` expression, plus the fact you have all those scalar functions (hopefully you're using SQL Server 2019 they are inline functions at least?) in this multi-line scalar function gives this a strong "smell" of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `CASE` returns a scalar value.

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#setting-a-value-in-a-transact-sql-variable) scalars can be assigned to variables.

However, do keep in mind -and make sure- that the select statement should return only **one row** (also mentioned in the documentation above).

The problem then comes down to the order of your assignment. Try this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_CaglarDeneme]
(@stok_kodu varchar(25))
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VAL As Float

    SELECT @VAL =
        CASE WHEN sto_mensei in ('REGULE') THEN
            (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod ,  getdate()-180 , getdate ()) +
            dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ()) + 
            dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ())) - 
            (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod, getdate ()-180 , getdate ()) +  
            dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ()))
        WHEN sto_mensei in ('PASIF','PROJE') THEN
            (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-90,getdate () ) +
            dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate () ) + 
            dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ())) - 
            (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ()) +  
            dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ()))
        WHEN sto_mensei in ('YAZLIK','KISLIK') THEN
            (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())
            + dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) + 
            dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())) - 
            (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) +  
            dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()))
        ELSE 0
        END
    FROM   dbo.STOKLAR  
    WHERE  (sto_kod=@stok_kodu)

    IF @VAL <0 SET @VAL =0
    RETURN @VAL
END
```

**Note:**
I would suggest that you tested a simpler version of your code first, to make sure that everything is running smoothly, that the syntax of your formulas are correct and the results are as expected.

For example:

- Eg 1. I noticed what appeared to be extra commas (`,`) before every `WHEN`.
- Eg 2. `REGULE` appears to be a word/string, but it's missing the `'`s.
- Eg 3. You were missing the `END` for the `CASE` statement.

(I corrected those issues already)

So if I were you I would try simpler versions such as the following first:

**TEST 1: ARE MY FORMULAS OK? AM I RETURNING A SINGLE ROW?**

```sql
SELECT (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod ,  getdate()-180 , getdate ()) +
        dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ()) + 
        dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ())) - 
        (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod, getdate ()-180 , getdate ()) +  
        dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-180 , getdate ())) AS FORMULA_1,
        
        (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-90,getdate () ) +
        dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate () ) + 
        dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ())) - 
        (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ()) +  
        dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-90 , getdate ())) AS FORMULA_2,
        
        (dbo.fn_F_UlusalSatisMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())
        + dbo.fn_F_UlusalVirmanMiktar(sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) + 
        dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeVerilenMiktar ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())) - 
        (dbo.fn_F_KonsinyeIadeAlınanMiktar  ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ()) +  
        dbo.fn_F_ToptaniadeMiktarFatura601 ( sto_kod , getdate ()-360 , getdate ())) AS FORMULA_3
FROM   dbo.STOKLAR  
WHERE  (sto_kod=@stok_kodu)
```

If so, then

**TEST 2: IS THE SYNTAX OF MY FUNCTION OK?**

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_CaglarDeneme]
(@stok_kodu varchar(25))
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VAL As Float

    SELECT @VAL =
        CASE WHEN sto_mensei in ('REGULE') THEN 1
        WHEN sto_mensei in ('PASIF','PROJE') THEN 2
        WHEN sto_mensei in ( 'YAZLIK','KISLIK') THEN 3
        ELSE 0
        END
    FROM   dbo.STOKLAR  
    WHERE  (sto_kod=@stok_kodu)

    IF @VAL <0 SET @VAL =0
    RETURN @VAL
END
```

If so, **THEN** I would run the first block of code in this solution, which is the full version.

Comment: Bünyamin, did it work? (Please consider marking the answer as correct if it did).